# MIUI theme made with MIUI theme creator creating problems

Tags: miui, themes

I have a Redmi note 5 running MIUI 9.6.2.0 | Stable. I made a theme using MIUI Theme Creator and successfully applied it, but after an hour or so, the theme went back to it's default one. This is happening no matter how many times I set it up.

What is the problem? And is there a way to solve it?

Comment: I think theme application doesn't support third party themes(like created by any person) which is not verified by community.

Comment: Then why can I apply it for even sometime?

Comment: https://android-fix.com/tips-and-tricks/22-themes-from-third-party-sources-not-supported.html Please look through this link.